# How do I get the coordinates of the ground and the wall? (AR Core)

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm using AR Core as Unity.

I used AR Core to recognize the ground and the wall, so can I get all the coordinate data that apply?

Or is there a way to know the distance between the cell phone and the wall that shoots the ray?